# conditional expectation of a Markov chain composed with a harmonic function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

In the lecture notes we have that $$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\sum_{y\in S} h(y)K(X_n,y)=h(X_n)$$ where $h$ is a harmonic function, $S$ is the countable state space of a Markov chain $(X_n)_n$ with $X_0=x\in S, x$ fixed and $K$ is the transition matrix. I am trying to understand how the first equality works (the second is immediate by the definition of a harmonic function) but I failed to succeed.

I know that this is an equivalent formulation of the Markov property which is: $$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \sigma(X_n)]$$

I tried to use integration:
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\int h(X_{n+1})d\mathbb{P}(\cdot\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=\sum_{y\in S}h(y)\int K(X_{n+1},y)d\mathbb{P}(\cdot\mid\mathcal{F}_n)$$
so now it remains to show: $$\int K(X_{n+1},y)d\mathbb{P}(\cdot\mid\mathcal{F}_n)=K(X_n,y)$$
but I don't see how to do this either.
Thanks for helping me out with this!!

edit: I think I understood it, but I would appreciate a confirmation.
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\sum_{y\in S} h(y)\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n)$$ by the markov property and the definition of the transition matrix we conclude that $$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n)=K(X_n,y)$$

Comment: The edit is correct. However, I do not exactly understand what you mean by $K(X_{n+1})$ in the integral, because $K$ should always take two arguments!

Comment: it is supposed to be $K(X_{n+1},y)$, indeed a typo thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Since you solved your problem, you should probably close the question :)

Comment: Or post the solution as an answer.

Comment: @MushuNrek how do I do that?

Comment: I think that @DavideGiraudo is right. The best thing would be to post your answer and accept it. This will help future people!

Answer (score 1):

Since I found the solution, I am answering my own question.
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\sum_{y\in S} h(y)\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n,X_{n-1},\ldots ,X_1)$$ by the markov property we have that:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n,X_{n-1},\ldots ,X_1)=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n)$$ and now the answer is trivial by using the definition of the transition matrix $K(x,y)=\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n=x)$ which implies:$$\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n)=K(X_n,y)$$ and thus we have:
$$\mathbb{E}[h(X_{n+1})\mid \mathcal{F}_n]=\sum_{y\in S} h(y)\mathbb{P}(X_{n+1}=y\mid X_n)=h(X_n)$$ where we used the definition of a harmonic function for the last equality.